# Foursquare API: get set of featured photos

Tags: android, foursquare

I'm working on Android app which uses Foursquare API. For fetching results I use [/venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint. I want to make fancy detail screen with set of photos as Foursquare does([example](https://foursquare.com/v/brooklyn-bridge-park--pier-2/51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942)) So, according to documentation, when I make request for nearby places, I use parameter `venuePhotos=1`, but always get one photo from the count result of featured photos ([example](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/explore%3Fll%3D40.7,-74%26venuePhotos%3D1)). Is this a bug of API or I got it wrong :) ?

I'm using [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) for monitoring response from certain requests.
here is my API request(I removed my client id and secret):

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?venuePhotos=1&limit=10&radius=500&v=20160215&ll=55.693053,12.584903&client_secret=//&client_id=//
```

**client_id:**

**client_secret:**

**limit:** 10

**ll:** 55.693053,12.584903

**radius:** 500

**v:** 20160215

**venuePhotos:** 1

And I get always one photo in photo count for regular and featured photos in every venue. Response example:

```
{"reasons": {},"venue": {"id": "4c41ae26af052d7fbba97d79","name": "Femmeren - jazz-værtshus","contact": {},"location": {},"categories": [],"verified": false,"stats": {},"price": {},"rating": 8.2,"ratingColor": "73CF42","ratingSignals": 11,"allowMenuUrlEdit": true,"photos": {"count": 1,"groups": []},"hereNow": {},"featuredPhotos": {"count": 1,"items": []}},"tips": [],"referralId": "e-0-4c41ae26af052d7fbba97d79-3"},
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not able to replicate this behavior. Can you paste the API call your making and the response with incorrect photo counts?

Comment: @enc_life Hi, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. The `venuePhotos=1` parameter will include a single photo in the response from the venues/explore endpoint. This is extremely useful if you need to display a single photo in a list of venues. To get more photos for a venue, you need to hit the [venues/photos](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos) endpoint and pass the venueId you want the photos from -> `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I reread documentation and found that it is actually one only one photo(which is the same as standard photo but more informative). Array response of featured photos misled me:)